# Security and backup if documents in library are not synced

Tags: security, backup, sync

Is there any reason why I would not want to store all of my business documents and not sync them? Should I have any concerns about security or losing data? I don't need to have my documents synced because I don't need them if I'm not online, but I don't know if there's a risk of losing the information.

Comment: where you want to store the documents, do you want locally or store them in document library?

Comment: I just want to store them in the document library.

Answer (score 0):

The documents are stored locally, so anyone with access to your computer would have access to those documents like they were any other locally stored document.

There is a minute amount of network traffic as the sync has to check if it's up to date regularly.

The only way to really risk losing the information (and this involves willful, perhaps laboriously foolish effort) is if you delete the local copies or vandalize them in such a way that the data inside of them is replaced, but if you have versioning turned on for the library or access to the SP recycle bin, that's a correctable issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just store the document in the library and dont want to sync them to local directories, their is no issue at all with your backup or security.

- backup depend upon the your Farm backup procedure.
- their is no risk of losing the information as far you have your backup process in place.
- I don't see the any security concern as long you have proper permission policy.